# WSO2 ESB and Rest with PUT request

Tags: web-services, rest, proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

I am attempting to proxy a restful service through the ESB. When I do GET requests everything works perfectly including things like 403 or 405 errors.

However when I try to do PUT requests I always get "Error in sender" and the message never gets back to the client. I even see in the logs on the ESB that the right message is being returned from the service to the ESB the ESB just doesn't seem to handle the return on the PUT request well.

Any idea what I would have to change? I think it might need some API setup but I can't figure out how to do that. I have found loads of examples of the actual XML but not how to actually set it up (through the GUI or otherwise).

I have also tried setting up in and out sequences as well as fault sequences but it always has the same result.

If I set the message format on the endpoint to REST or POX it doesn't work either.

Also I have tried logging the request type on the in sequence and for GET requests this again works as expected but for PUT it just doesn't even log anything and just stops.

Anything I have to do to get PUT request working?

Thanks,

-- 
Bram Cymet
Software Developer
Canadian Bank Note Co. Ltd.
613-608-9752

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write a REST API to do this. Here is a [simple post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/09/rest-support-in-wso2esb-introduction.html) on how to configure the restapi.